# AngularJs select ng-options not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I am trying to make a select in AngularJS without success.

I have two objects:

**AnimalType**

```
 $scope.animalTypeArray = {idAnimalType:"xxx", name:"yyy"}; ...
```

and **Animal**

```
$scope.animal = new animalObj(); //This one is empty.

  this.idAnimalType,

  this.name,

  this.age ...
```

what I want to do is to show a list of **animalsType** and put the idAnimalType into the idAnimalType of the **Animal** obj.

I am trying this:

```
<select  class="form-control select-primary" id="animalType" ng-model="animal.idAnimalType" ng-options="animalType.getName() for animalType in animalTypeArray track by animalType.getIdAnimalType()">
```

controller:

```
//objectsdeclaration
$scope.animalType = new animalTypeObj();
$scope.animal = new animalObj();

$scope.animalTypeArray = new Array();
$scope.animalType;

//objects creation of animalType to show on the select
var animalType = new animalTypeObj();
animalType.construct(1,"Bird");
$scope.animalTypeArray.push(animalType);

var animalType = new animalTypeObj();
animalType.construct(2,"Insect");
$scope.animalTypeArray.push(animalType);
```

When I print **console.log($scope.animalTypeArray);** the object array is shown OK.

The select is shown with as many results as the array have, but they only print a blank char, and not the expected name.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? Its a rough version of what you are trying to do ... I have improvised animalTypeObj and animalObj as follows ...

```
  function animalTypeObj(){
     var that = this;

     that.construct = function(type, name){
     that.type = type;
     that.name = name;
     }

     that.getName = function(){return that.name;}
     that.getIdAnimalType = function(){return that.type; }
}

function animalObj(){
     var that = this;
     that.idAnimalType = {};
     that.name = '';
     that.age = 0;
}
```

I have skipped

http://jsfiddle.net/c2zamajc/5/

Hope it helps ....

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not providing much of the code i assume you need something like this:

```
    <select  class="form-control select-primary" id="animalType" ng-model="animal.idAnimalType"
      ng-options="animalType.idAnimalType as animalType.name for animalType in animalTypeArray">
   </select>
```